# how to delete excel file after export through PHPExcel in codeigniter , unlink() is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am fetching data from database and export it into excel file using phpexcel5.
that is working fine but i don't want to save this excel file into my server folder. I am using unlink function for delete this excel file but it is not working .

Below is my code -

```
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"");
header("Cache-control: private");

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save("export/$filename");
header("location: " . base_url() . "export/$filename");
unlink(base_url() . "export/$filename");
```

*export is my folder name where excel file will be stored.
I want to delete this excel file from export folder.*

Comment: You don't unlink it through a url, you unlink it through the filesystem... `unlink("export/$filename");`

Comment: unlink should work check file path you using

Comment: P.S. Why even bother saving the file to the server, when you could save it directly to the browse?

Answer (score 0):

unlink will not work with **absolute url**. you need to use the **relative url** for deleting the file.

for e.g. your folder structure like below.

```
- application
- assets   
   - export
     - file_name.xls
```

than your code will be like below.

```
if(file_exist('./assets/export/file_name.xls')) {
    unlink('./assets/export/file_name.xls');
}
```

I hope this will work.